# How to set default navbar tab when page load

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set the default navbar tab when the page is load.
I'm trying to set default navbar tab is 'Sell my car' this tab is open when the page is load.
how I can do this.
There is navbar tabs.

```js
function Default() {
    var tab= document.getElementsByClassName('defaulttab');
    window.onload(tab).click();
}
```

```html
 <a class="nav-link tablink active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#my-adverts" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">My Adverts</a>
<a class="nav-link tablink defaulttab" id="v-pills-profile-tab "  data-toggle="pill" href="#sell-your-car" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Sell my car</a>
<a class="nav-link tablink" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#change-package" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Change Package</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `active` class on your default nav link, no additional js is needed:

```html
<a class="nav-link tablink" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#my-adverts" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="false">My Adverts</a>
<a class="nav-link tablink active" id="v-pills-profile-tab "  data-toggle="pill" href="#sell-your-car" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="true">Sell my car</a>
<a class="nav-link tablink" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#change-package" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Change Package</a>
```